# Configure commitizen to bump a default version

Tags: commitizen

Can we configure commitizen command

```
cz bump
```

to bump to a default version (i.e. PATCH ) if there is no commit bump_pattern (i.e.  ^(break|new|fix|hotfixi)) in the commit message?

This is the part in my .cz.yaml that controls the bumping behavior:

```
  bump_map:
  break: MAJOR
  fix: PATCH
  hotfix: PATCH
  new: MINOR
  "": PATCH
  bump_pattern: ^(break|new|fix|hotfix|.*)
```

after saving the file and running 'cz bump' I see that the .cz.yaml file was updated to:

```
  bump_map:
  ? ''
  : PATCH
  break: MAJOR
  fix: PATCH
  hotfix: PATCH
  new: MINOR
```

I know that my regex isn't correct but even if updating it, how do I configure the 'bump_map' to assign PATCH on every commit that doesn't start with a type:?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here is the way I solved this:
In the pyproject.toml (I am using poetry) add those line

```
[tool.commitizen]
name = "cz_customize"

[tool.commitizen.customize]
bump_map = {"break" = "MAJOR", "new" = "MINOR", "fix" = "PATCH", "hotfix" = "PATCH", " " = "PATCH"}
```

in commitizen yaml configuration file it should be something like this:

```
commitizen:
  name: cz_customize
  customize:
    bump_map:
      break: MAJOR
      fix: PATCH
      hotfix: PATCH
      new: MINOR
      " ": PATCH
```

You were almost there but it seems that you don't need to modify the "bump_pattern"